# How can I spread a sub to a multiple range of cells?

Tags: excel, vba, function

The purpose of this code is to update the date in a cell as a certain cell's contents are changed.

Since this was originally coded inside a sub, I now need to expand this code to a range of multiple cells. Ie. At this moment, the code only takes cell D4 and updates cell L4, I want to be able to drag this function down so it can reach a multiple range of cells; take D5 and update L5 etc.

Here's my code as the sub:

```
Dim oldValue

Public Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
oldValue = Target.Worksheet.Range("D4").Value
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 
  If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("D4")) Is Nothing Then
    If oldValue <> Target.Worksheet.Range("D4").Value Then
        Target.Worksheet.Range("L4").Value = Date
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

The problem here, is that I don't know how to properly expand my code to match a further selection of cells. Here's my attempt:

```
Dim oldValue

Public Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
oldValue = Target.Worksheet.Range("D4", "D21").Value
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("D4", "D21")) Is Nothing Then
    If oldValue <> Target.Worksheet.Range("D4", "D21").Value Then
        Target.Worksheet.Range("L4", "L21").Value = Date
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

EDIT: The sub I have written only applies to one cell, I am trying to work out a way to have it spread out to a certain selection of cells. Ie. D4:D12 which updates the date in L4:L12 accordingly.

If anyone could help me, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Worksheet_Change` is an event handler, so it *has to* be a `Sub` to function. What exactly is meant by "I now need to expand this code to a range of multiple cells"?

Comment: In addition to Comintern's comment, I think your real issue is identifying the cause of: "Previously, when refreshing my workbook, it updated the date, now it does not, and only updates when the value inside the cell has changed"

Comment: *if I am not mistaken.*  You are :)  A subroutine can easily operate on a range of cells.

Comment: So is `Worksheet_SelectionChange`. It can't be a function either. Instead of asking how to do something you can't, ask about what you're trying to accomplish instead. (BTW, you *are* wrong. Both of those event handlers already accept a range of cells - that's what a `Range` is by definition.)

Comment: So I would advise this: re-write/edit your question with a better description of *what you need*, instead of *what you think you need*. Example input/output scenarios would be helpful as well.

Comment: This code only applies to one cell, I want to drag it down a range of cells so it then applies to those cells aswell, not just 'D4' and 'L4'. @DavidZemens I want it like that, I do not want the cells updating when  refresh the workbook. That part of the problem is fixed.

Comment: I have edited my description, please let me know what else you require in order to fix my problem, thanks.

Comment: I think you are confusing the `Worksheet_Change` event (which is triggered when there is a change on the worksheet) with a User-Defined-Function (which is a function that you can enter into an Excel cell, in a similar way to functions such as `SUM` and `VLOOKUP`).  The `Worksheet_Change` event applies to the **whole** worksheet, while a UDF applies only to the cell in which it is used (although it can be used multiple times in multiple cells, and thus can be "copied down" if you wanted to).  I am pretty certain that what you want to do is impossible with a UDF.

Comment: It isn't clear what you want, exactly. If you want a UDF -- just write it directly. I don't see how thinking of it as a modification of a worksheet change sub which doesn't do what you want is particularly helpful. Just scrap what you have and start again.

Comment: @YowE3K The sub I have written only applies to one cell, I guess I am trying to work out a way to have it spread out to a certain selection of cells. Ie. `D4:D12` which updates the date in `L4:L12` accordingly.

Comment: The easiest way to do what you want is, in the `SelectionChange` event, store away the 9 different values instead of the one value you currently do, and then, in the `Change` event process things if any of the cells in D4:D12 are the Target and the corresponding "old value" is different to the "current value".  It is very hard (probably impossible) to store an "old value" using a UDF.

Comment: @YowE3K probably could be done with a module/static variable and/or a `Name` in the worksheet, but it would be convoluted to do either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
Dim oldValue()

Public Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    oldValue = Me.Range("D4:D12").Value
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("D4:D12")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim c As Range
        For Each c In Intersect(Target, Me.Range("D4:D12"))
            'Check value against what is stored in "oldValue" (row 4 is in position 1, row 5 in position 2, etc)
            If oldValue(c.Row - 3, 1) <> c.Value Then
                'Update value in column L (8 columns to the right of column D)
                c.Offset(0, 8).Value = Date 'or possibly "= Now()" if you need the time of day that the cell was updated
            End If
        Next
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: There is no date showing in cell L4, or anywhere else, even when I am changing the value of the data. It's a bit hard to debug your code as I am sort of new to VBA scripting within Excel.

Thanks for your help though!

Comment: @juiceb0xk - can you put a breakpoint on the first line of each subroutine and just make sure that it is reaching the code.  Other than the code being in the wrong sheet, or EnableEvents being False, I can't see why the code wouldn't run.  (It was working fine when I tested it before posting.)

Comment: The code isn't breaking anywhere. It is in the correct sheet too. I have put a breakpoint on each line of code and none of them are breaking at all.

Comment: It sounds like somehow `Application.EnableEvents` got set to `False` but never went through to the end of the code to set it back to `True` again.  Go to the Immediate Window in the VBA IDE and type in `Application.EnableEvents = True` (and press Enter), then try again.  (I have to go to a meeting now - I won't be back for about 4 hours.)

Comment: It's giving me an `invalid outside procedure` compile error. I'm not sure where else to type `Application.EnableEvents = True`. If I completely remove the EnableEvents code, it still doesn't update the date.

Comment: The immediate window (if not already visible) can probably (possibly depending on what version of Excel you are using) be displayed in the IDE by selecting View / Immediate Window, or usually Ctrl-G works too.

Comment: Okay, thank you for that insight. It's all working now, that's awesome thanks, now to debug your code and find out what really is going on.

Comment: Just remember that, if you stop the code after `Application.EnableEvents = False` has been executed, no further Events will be executed until you go through the `Application.EnableEvents = True` statement.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Set up a hidden sheet to hold the old values.

---

```
Sub SetupMirrorValues()
    With Worksheets.Add
        .Name = "MirrorValues"
        .visibilty = xlSheetVeryHidden
        .Range("D4:D10,D12,D14:D20") = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D4:D10,D12,D14:D20")
    End With
End Sub
```

---

In the `Worksheet_Change` event handler, you would check the `Target` cells that intersect with the range you want to monitor.  If there are differences then you update the timestamp and the cell on the hidden sheet that corresponds to the changed cell.

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim cell As Range, DRange As Range
    Set DRange = Range("D4:D10,D12,D14:D20")
    If Not Intersect(DRange, Target) Is Nothing Then
        For Each cell In Intersect(DRange, Target)

            If cell.Value <> Worksheets("MirrorValues").Range(cell.Address) Then
                cell.EntireRow.Cells(1, "L").Value = Now
                Worksheets("MirrorValues").Range(cell.Address) = cell.Value
            End If

        Next
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

Comment: That's awesome, I'll have to try it out later, but thanks in advance. I was going to do this without VBA, but looks as if it can be done.

Comment: Good luck in advanced!!  Cheers